# Uncaught Except Invalid Form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error in the console: uncaught exception: Invalid form

when I load the page.

I believe the line that is causing it is this. I think this because I removed little by little and when I got to this part then it removed the error in my console.

```
<?php echo form_label('Booking Date', 'booking_date'); ?>
<?php 
$attributes = array(
'id' => 'datetime',
'name' => 'booking_date',
'class' => 'required hasDatepicker valid',
'type' => 'datetime',
'data-date-relative' => 'now' 
);
?>
<?php echo form_input($attributes); ?>
```

All code

```
<h2 class="grid_12">Book Event</h2>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="grid_12">
<div class="box wizard" data-step="1">
    <div class="header">
        <?php echo img('assets/peach/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/shadeless/application--arrow.png'); ?>
        <?php echo heading('Book Event', 3); ?>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content with-actions">
        <div class="steps">
            <ul>
                <li class="current">
                    <a href="#step_1">
                        <span>1</span>
                        <div>
                            <strong>Book Event</strong>
                            <small></small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#step_2">
                        <span>2</span>
                        <div>
                            <strong>Schedule Matches</strong>
                            <small></small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#step_3">
                        <span>3</span>
                        <div>
                            <strong>Verify Event</strong>
                            <small></small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wiz_page step_1">
            <div class="wiz_sidebar grid_3">
                <span>1</span>
                <div>
                   <strong>Book Event</strong>
                   <small></small>
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="wiz_content grid_9">
                <h3>Event Setup</h3>
                <?php echo form_open('newevent'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_label('Event Name', 'event_name'); ?>
                    <?php 
                    $options = array();
                    $options['default'] = 'Please Select An Option';
                    foreach ( $event_names AS $name ) 
                    {
                        $options[$name->id] = $name->event_name;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php echo form_dropdown('eventname', $options, 'default'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_label('Event Label', 'event_label'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_input('event_label', ''); ?>
                    <?php echo form_label('Booking Date', 'booking_date'); ?>
                    <?php 
                    $attributes = array(
                        'id' => 'datetime',
                        'name' => 'booking_date',
                        'class' => 'required hasDatepicker valid',
                        'type' => 'datetime',
                        'data-date-relative' => 'now'
                    );
                    ?>
                    <?php print_r($attributes); ?>
                    <?php echo form_input($attributes); ?>
                    <?php echo form_label('Arena', 'arenas'); ?>
                    <?php 
                    $options = array();
                    $options['default'] = 'Please Select An Option';
                    foreach ( $arenas AS $arena )
                    {
                        $options[$arena->id] = $arena->arena_name;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php echo form_dropdown('arenas', $options, 'default'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_label('Introduction', 'introduction'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_textarea('introduction', ''); ?>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="actions-left">
            <button class="prev">&laquo; Back</button>
        </div>
        <div class="actions-right">
            <button class="next">Forward &raquo;</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of .content -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Link to the live page: [Link](http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/events/bookevent)

Answer (score 1):

It's a JavaScript error and it originates from this snippet:

```
$.each(ids, function () {
    if (this.indexOf('dp') == 0 || $('label[for=' + this + ']').length) {
        id = this;
    }
});

if (!id) {
    throw "Invalid form";
}
```

As you can see, you're throwing an "Invalid form" exception if `id` evaluates to false.

Comment: The exception is located at line 210 of script.js. Your console should display the line number for you, and you should be able to click it to be taken to that specific line.

Comment: yeah it doesn't it won't let me click on anything on it

Comment: But I"m still trying to understand why I'm getting that error.

Comment: I'm using Chrome v19 for what it's worth. What exactly are you expecting `id` to be at that point in the code?

Comment: I'm just trying to use http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/files/templates/admin/peachv1.2/Template/forms.html as my template

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by you're expecting `id` to be datetime, but `id`, at that point in the code, is evaluating to false - thus, the exception is thrown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12717/discussion-between-user1406861-and-colin)